# How to give padding to child table in Prawn PDF?

Tags: ruby, prawn

I have generated a nested table using Prawn but it occupies the whole space of the parent table so it is becoming difficult for users to identify which is a child.

Is there any way where we can give padding to child table so it can be little separated in terms of look/UI

Right now the table in PDF is looking like this

[image]

below is the real table and I want to convert that to pdf using Prawn. I need similar padding in PDF.

[image: see the image below]

Comment: Do you really need nesting tables?

Comment: Yes, @iGian I need it.